# Animação jQuery antes da submissão do formulário

Tags: jquery, formulário, animação

Eu tenho este código, a animação acontece mas o redireccionamento para a próxima página (`work.php`) não.

Ou seja, não está a entrar na condição `if (isset($_POST...`. Se eu comentar o pedaço de código responsável pela animação o redireccionamento já acontece, mas não é isso que pretendo:

**index.php:**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $firstName = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
    $firstName = str_replace(array('.', ',', ';', '?', '/', '|', '(', ')', 'º', '+', '#', '$', '@', "'", '"'), '' , $firstName);
    $firstName = trim(ucwords($firstName));

    if(!empty($firstName)) {
        $user->saveCookie($firstName);
    }

    header('Location: work.php');
}
require_once('includes/head.php');
?>
<body onunload="">
    <div id="wrapper">
.....
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
.....
</html>
```

**js.js:**

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('#footer').css({
            "position":"absolute",
            "bottom": "5px"
        });
        $('#wrapper').animate({
            "margin-top": "-1000px"
        }, 700, function(){
            $('form').submit();
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Kazzkiq, "redirecCionamento" é pt_PT ;)

Comment: hehe pois, mas por acaso eu também sou :P

Comment: @brasofilo My bad, eu dei uma pesquisada rápida e todos os resultados em português que vi não tinham o segundo "c", provavelmente por serem do Brasil, por isso editei a palavra.

Comment: Sem problema :)

Comment: @Kazzkiq, sem problemas, eu também já "corrigi" o Sergio só pra terminar me dando conta que é preciso tomar esse cuidado de não abrasileirar o português alheio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, 'submit' é uma palavra reservada de javascript logo o 'name' do 'input[type="submit"]' não pode ser 'submit', entra de alguma maneira em conflito com a função 'submit()' de javascript:

1ª alteração: HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input name="userName" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" name="nameCookie">
</form>
```

Depois disto parece que o form é submitido pois é feito um reload à página mas continua sem ser processado pela condição 'if(isset(...))' porque o redirecionamento não acontece. Continuava de alguma maneira a haver algum tipo de conflito com a parte de javascript, então alterei o argumento do 'isset', para em vez de ser o 'name' do "input[type='submit']" (nameCookie), passou a ser o 'name' do "input[type='text']" (userName):

2ª alteração: PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['userName'])) {
    $firstName = htmlentities($_POST['userName']);
    ...
    if(!empty($firstName)) {
        $user->saveCookie($firstName);
    }
    header('Location: work.php');
}
```

Não fiz qualquer alteração no js.js.

PS: Não sei (se alguém souber explique sff) os motivos técnicos para que esta segunda alteração seja necessária, mas resultou.

Answer (score 0):

O clique em "Yours" não está a executar este código. O código que está a ser executado é:

```
$('#formName').click(function(){
            $(this).css({
                "text-decoration": (underline = !underline) ? "none" : "underline"
            })
            $('form, h2, p').fadeToggle(500);
            $('h3').stop().animate({
                "top": (down = !down) ? "330px" : "290px"
            }, 500);
            $('form input').focus();
        });
```

Comment: Dsculpe, percebi agora o que quer dizer. Clique em "yours" para aparecer o form